# How to zip multiple folders in 7zip?

Tags: windows, compression, zip, 7-zip

I have a folder, lets say, `MAIN`. Inside this folder, there are many folders(say `f1,f2,f2...`) which has subfolders and files in them. Now I need to zip these folders(`f1,f2,f3...`) and their contents (which might be subfolders and files) into separate zips(`f1.7z, f2.7z, f3.7z ...`) and put them under `MAIN` folder.

Also, I need to use these settings for all the zips. 
.7z, LZMA2, Ultra, 1024MB(Dictionary size), 273(Word size), Solid, Compress shared files.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a basic batch compress job can be done [thus](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-7Zip-to-Create-Multiple-Compressed-Folders-in-One-Go). You will however need to edit the command as necessary to accommodate your specific requirements. This can be done through the use of various 'switches'; the syntax for doing so is available [here](http://docs.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/).

Comment: I already checked that First link. It makes the output file to be in one single zip file, doesn't it? But Unfortunately, I don't want it that way.  Thanks for the second link. Though it might take me weeks to find what i want by myself, I've no other way. If you already know how to do code to meet my requirements, please advise so.

Comment: @prashanth: The first link had actually worked fine for me. I just made a bat file with the contents as `for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\"` and put in in my `MAIN` folder. When I ran it, I got each folder in a separate 7z file.

Comment: Thank You Ron. I didn't read it properly. It works like a charm now. You saved me a lot of time. :)

Comment: @prashanth: Happy to help. :) Please do mark the answer as accepted if you're happy with it.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that, expect for voting the answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

This should work reasonably well:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec p7zip {} \;
```

You should be able to construct your final command line from that easily.

- `-maxdepth 1`
  Only search 1 directory deep
- `-type d`
  Only search for directories
- `-exec p7zip {} \;`
  Pass every found item to `p7zip` - creating a `.7z` archive of the folder.

Comment: Actually, i'm not exposed to CLI. So would you please tell me the exact code to perform this?  Also, if we are to keep maxdepth = 1, won't the files in the subfolders be excluded?  And there is no mention of the settings that i intend to use. How do i specify that?

Comment: @prashanth: You'll need to use the command-line version of 7zip, the usage of which is documented in the 7zip Help file that comes with the executable -- should be listed under "Programs" from the Start menu.

Comment: p7zip of course is the command line version of 7-Zip for Unix/Linux. 7za.exe is what you'd use if you were on Windows.